# nginx redirect multiple hosts with SSL certificate

Tags: nginx, certbot

Certbot is generating and automated redirect, but only for a single host.

the `server_name` block lists multiple domains which are properly being served via https.  However, a certbot generated block

```
server {
  if ($host = [1st_host_listed_in_server_block] ) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

which is not what I am after, wanting all hosts to redirect.  The real odd part is that a different server has the exact same set-up generated by Certbot, but the redirect of a single host works for all server names...

How can I ensure all http requests for this nginx configuration file (there are others) are redirected to https?

Answer (score 1):

Take out the if condition and replace it with listen 80;

If it's the only server listening on port 80 then it will process all requests on that port, regardless of client host request

Comment: will this override other site configuration files?  whatever the case it is not working, as it is on another server.  Other assumption: the other server has other serve configuration files non conflicting, while the one invoked in the question does?